# Shopify CLI 3.0 making REST API call from frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to Shopify CLI 3.0. I have downloaded the starter template from `yarn create @shopify/app --template php`. Now I am trying to register the web hook from my apps.

I made the ajax call from frontend using the below code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api/orderCreateWebhooks")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ fact }) => console.log(fact))
     .catch((error) => {
    });
 }, []);
```

And In my backend code, I have below code.

```
 Route::get('/api/orderCreateWebhooks', function (Request $request) {
/** @var AuthSession */
$session = $request->get('shopifySession'); // Provided by the shopify.auth middleware, guaranteed to be active

$client = new Rest($session->getShop(), $session->getAccessToken());
$data = [
    "webhook"=> [
      "topic"=> "orders/create",
      "address"=> "https://9918-110-44-127-202.ngrok.io/",
      "format"=> "json"
    ]
    ];
$result = $client->post('/admin/api/2022-04/webhooks.json',$data);

return response($result->getDecodedBody());
})->middleware('shopify.auth:online');
```

With this ajax call, the call is made instead to `/api/auth?shop=` URL with 500 response HTTP code. Is there any thing missing that needs to be done?

There is no well documentation on this from Shopify as well. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

After looking in to the network request I found that the request are being redirect with 302 status code. Please find the screenshot below. It seems like some authentication issue. How can be authenticate the API that we are requesting?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: #1 Did you solve your problem? #2 "With this ajax call..." I think is not ajax, it is php. The ajax is /api/orderCreateWebhooks #3  Share us the response headers. When 302 is returned there is another header called: Location #4 Since `$session->getShop()` is used, a login is required #5 Put logs in the php side to detect in which line occurs the error.

Comment: @JRichardsz I tried logs in php side and request has not reached to php side.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing authentication on your original code. You would need to provide some Authorization token [Authorization - Bearer JWT TOKEN] in your request or you need to pass ShopifySession in the query parameter variables.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api/orderCreateWebhooks")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ fact }) => console.log(fact))
     .catch((error) => {
    });
 }, []);
```

would become something like,

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api/orderCreateWebhooks?shopifySession=", 
  {  method: 'get'
   })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ fact }) => console.log(fact))
     .catch((error) => {
    });
 }, []);
```

Mentioned below is a general format of fetch requests

```
fetch('URL_GOES_HERE', { 
    method: 'post', 
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password'), 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }), 
    body: 'A=1&B=2'
});
```